# Watch HD 1080p HDMI/VGA on Computer

Tags: windows, vga

I would like to essentially watch my television network on my computer.

Basically the television network box outputs HDMI/VGA.  I would prefer this to be cheap as possible but don't mind spending some money.  I am currently running W10 but have linux and MacOS boxes also.

Essentially I want a hdmi/vga to USB converter.

Example [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B017NL8OQK/?coliid=I2H8TJTF6FSJ3A&colid=XO7UDK2DFTFK&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017NL8OQK)

Ideally I want one somebody has used.

Comment: It’s really difficult to find “video capture from HDMI source”, which is what you’re looking for.   I think it’s all about video copyrights and licensing. There are a few out there.  I purchased two once, it worked ok for some channels (from cable) but not for others.  It’s been awhile (years) so I don’t remember all the details that I once knew, but there are far more options for over-the-air video capture than “from HDMI” signal.  The idea is they don’t want you to setup shop re-selling premium content.

Comment: @Tyson okay surely vga doesn't have these issues though.  Mind posting which one you used?  Also with torrents I find there concern slightly silly.

Comment: I don’t actually know anymore, like I said it been awhile.  I took a quick look on google, and even quick look in my junk parts, to see if I knew before I wrote the above comment. At the time I was trying to build an HD Windows Media Center computer. (My first media center computer was SD and worked awesomely).  I finally gave up on the second and just leased the cable companies DVR, basically my only problem was video capture from HDMI, the test worked.

Comment: Are you looking for a PCI card to insert into your desktop, or are you looking for a standalone device that you can hook up to your monitor? What cable provider do you have? What is the expected input? Coax?

Comment: @Cfinley USB card.  The provider is ATT.  Input as the question States is vga or hdmi.

Comment: @William Are you basically looking for an HDMI/VGA input device that plugs into a USB port?

Comment: @Cfinley yes one that ideally someone has used

Comment: @Cfinley please tell me what else to add.  I have linked to even an example but I would ideally like to use one somebody else has.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which features and accessories you want, some can sling to your phone:

- [Hauppauge - WinTV-dualHD USB Video Recorder](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hauppauge-wintv-dualhd-usb-video-recorder-black/4793702.p?skuId=4793702) - Black - U$70

[image: Stick]

- [Hauppauge WinTV-quadHD PCIe Card](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1261230-REG/hauppauge_1609_wintv_quadhd_pcie_card.html) - U$100

[image: Card]

- [Diamond ATI Theater HD 750 PCIE Tuner Card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003F8O690) -U$46

[image: Card + Remote Control]

- [Terk HD Digital TV Tuner with DVR Capability](https://www.terk.com/tv-tuner/?sku=TUNVR1#customer-reviews) - U$48

[image: HDMI Output]

Comment: no pci slots on my computer and the last one is s-video only which isn't HD.

Comment: Non of the linked examples are VGA/HDMI

Comment: The [first one](http://www.hauppauge.com/pages/products/data_dualhd.html) works with VGA/HDMI (assuming that your computer has such ports). A standalone box with VGA/HDMI outputs that doesn't use a computer is off topic.

Comment: No that is coax not hdmi/vga minus 1

Comment: I've added a fourth example that outputs HDMI and doesn't require a computer, is that what you wanted? --- The first one uses coax for the **input**, the **output** is whatever is supported by your computer/laptop.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B017NL8OQK/?coliid=I2H8TJTF6FSJ3A&colid=XO7UDK2DFTFK&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it

Comment: What I linked is what I am looking for but my question must not be  clear.

Comment: @Rob In the future, can you limit your answers to include only one product please? That way the community can vote on individual pieces of hardware. Otherwise it looks like you are just throwing up products just to see what sticks.

Comment: @Cfinley - I will do as you have asked. The reason I suggested different products with good reviews is because I didn't want to *advertise* a specific product and promote one brand over other equally good choices, initially William wasn't clear if it was Laptop or Desktop so vastly different but equally good choices were offered. Based on the votes "nothing has stuck" and I've moved on to more productive Q&A's - I don't mind deleting my answer if deletion of the question is eminent since there's been an edit that's made it no more clear than the original, nor has a recent comment.